# LLVM (3.5+) PassManager vs LegacyPassManager

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, llvm

I'm working on a new language using the LLVM C++ API and would like to take advantage of optimization passes. (***Note:*** I'm currently using the latest from source LLVM which I believe equates to 3.8)

I have yet to find any examples that use the new [PassManager](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/classllvm_1_1PassManager.html) and even [Clang](http://clang.llvm.org/) is still utilizing the [LegacyPassManager](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/classllvm_1_1legacy_1_1PassManager.html).

I have come across posts such as [this](http://adriansampson.net/blog/clangpass.html) that are several years old now that mention the new [PassManager](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/classllvm_1_1PassManager.html), but they all still use the legacy system.

Is there any examples/tutorials on how to use this new(ish) [PassManager](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/classllvm_1_1PassManager.html)?  Should new LLVM projects prefer [PassManager](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/classllvm_1_1PassManager.html) to [LegacyPassManager](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/classllvm_1_1legacy_1_1PassManager.html)?  Does [Clang](http://clang.llvm.org/) plan on migrating or is this why the Legacy system has stuck around?

Comment: Can't answer as to the plan, but LegacyPassManagers is still being used for the latest 3.8 sources from Nov 6th. I'd expect a better place to ask this question would be the LLVM mailing list, as that's where the people actually developing LLVM "lives", and those are the people who have the actual plans. [I expect the answer is "yes, eventually"]

Comment: So far I'm seeing much the same.  I will likely join in on the mailing list fun as I have gathered a rather large list of questions, however, I find SO to be a much better format for archiving these sorts of questions to better serve others later.  As a developer I'm actually very unsatisfied with mailing list search results LOL.  You always tend to find them in pieces and then the > reply format is atrocious.  I'm sure there is a front-end people tend to view those things from, but I normally just land on them from google searches.

Comment: Feel free to write an answer to your question when you get one... I do agree that it's often easier to read the answers on SO than other places. But everyone doesn't use SO, and people like Chandler Carruth that is one of the people behind the new PassManager is quite active on the LLVM mailing list.

Comment: I will most definitely update as I find more information.  I'm developer several parts concurrently so it may take a few days for me to come back to this part.  Thank you for the info!!

Comment: I should add that my compiler is also still using the Legacy pass manager.

Answer (score 7):

From what I've gathered with help from the #llvm IRC:

```
FunctionPassManager FPM;
//Use the PassInfoMixin types
FPM.addPass(InstCombinePass());

//Register any analysis passes that the transform passes might need
FunctionAnalysisManager FAM;

//Use the AnalysisInfoMixin types
FAM.registerPass([&] { return AssumptionAnalysis(); });
FAM.registerPass([&] { return DominatorTreeAnalysis(); });
FAM.registerPass([&] { return BasicAA(); });
FAM.registerPass([&] { return TargetLibraryAnalysis(); });

FPM.run(*myFunction, FAM);
```

But to avoid the hassle of manually registering each pass you can use `PassBuilder` to register the analysis passes

```
FunctionPassManager FPM;
FPM.addPass(InstCombinePass());

FunctionAnalysisManager FAM;

PassBuilder PB;
PB.registerFunctionAnalyses(FAM);

FPM.run(*myFunction, FAM);
```

Comment: This worked for me! The key part I was missing was `PB.registerFunctionAnalyses(FAM)`. Without it I was getting a segfault.

Comment: I still get segfaults, even when calling `PB.registerFunctionAnalysis`

Comment: I followed the code [here](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/release/11.x/clang/lib/CodeGen/BackendUtil.cpp#L1174) : Create an AnalyzerManager for each type (Module, Function, Loop, and CGSCC), pass each of them to the PassBuilder to register their analysis passes, and then called `PB.crossRegisterProxies(LAM, FAM, CGAM, MAM);` to cross-register everything.

Answer (score 5):

Extending Lukes answer, with `PassBuilder` you can build predefined "out of box" simplification pipelines with different optimization levels:

```
llvm::FunctionAnalysisManager FAManager;
llvm::PassBuilder passBuilder;

passBuilder.registerFunctionAnalyses(FAManager);

passBuilder.buildFunctionSimplificationPipeline(
        llvm::PassBuilder::OptimizationLevel::O2,
        llvm::PassBuilder::ThinLTOPhase::None);
```

which will add a bunch of passes to `FunctionAnalysisManager`. This may simplify your life. The best place to see the full set of passes added for each `OptimizationLevel` is [the original sources](http://llvm.org/doxygen/PassBuilder_8cpp_source.html#l00338).